# Error message ''$.metadata' is null or not an object.' using a validation plugin in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using [a validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) in jQuery.

My code in Internet Explorer gives an error as:

> '$.metadata' is null or not an object.

#### My Partial Code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $.validator.setDefaults({
          submitHandler: function() {
               alert("OK");
          }
       }); 
         
       $.metadata.setType("attr", "validate"); 
       $("#email").validate();
});
```

How do I rectify the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you didn't include [metadata plugin](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/metadata/jquery.metadata.js). Please review code of your page.